# Faster way to compute a sum within a sum?

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I would like a time efficient way to calculate a sum of the following form:

```
y = ConstantArray[0,5];
x = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5};
j = 2;

For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++,
 y[[i]] = x[[i]] + Sum[x[[n - 1]]*Exp[Sum[x[[m - 1]], {m, n, i}], {n, j, i}]
 ]
```

This produces an output of the following form:

```
{x1,
 x1*Exp[x1] + x2, 
 x1*Exp[x1 + x2] + x2*Exp[x2] + x3, 
 x1*Exp[x1 + x2 + x3] + x2*Exp[x2 + x3] + x3*Exp[x3] + x4,
 x1*Exp[x1 + x2 + x3 + x4] + x2*Exp[x2 + x3 + x4] + x3*Exp[x3 + x4] + x4*Exp[x4] + x5}
```

I would like to perform this sort of calculation for an array of about 300,000 data points to simulate cumulative decay. I am aware of the limitations of the Sum function with regards to computational speed, but I am struggling to recreate this sort of output structure with other functions such as Total or Accumulate. Can anyone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An iterative algorithm can compute this in about a second on my machine.

```
n = 300000;
x = RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, n];
y = ConstantArray[0., n];

y = ConstantArray[0., Length[x]];
y[[1]] = x[[1]];
Do[
  y[[i + 1]] = Exp[x[[i]]] y[[i]] + x[[i + 1]], 
  {i, 1, Length[x] - 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.758239

As many exponentials are involved, it is not unlikely that floating point over- or underflows occur. These would slow down the process a little.

Answer (score 5):

@HenrikSchumacher's iteration expressed with [`FoldList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html):

```
n = 300000;
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
y = FoldList[#1*E^#2[[1]] + #2[[2]] &, x[[1]], Partition[x, 2, 1]]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(*    0.139428    *)
```

Unfortunately, the more natural [`FoldPairList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html) is ten times slower:

```
n = 300000;
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
y = FoldPairList[(#1 + #2) {1, E^#2} &, 0, x]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(*    1.37965    *)
```